# Disproof of Gelfond-Schnieder Theorem

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

The Gelfond Schneider theorem somewhere says that "There exist **2** such **irrational numbers a and b**(where a doesn't equal to b), **a<sup>b</sup>** is rational.
The solution is taken as (in many answers in stack exchange as well, and otherwise too) the one that follows-

a = $ \sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}} $

b = $ \sqrt{2} $

In that case, this would be the solution-

[image: solution using root 2]

Great!, this solution is all right, 2 is rational...

**But what if I tell you that these are not the only two such numbers and infinite MORE examples exist ?**

So, let me take three variables - a( irrational ), b( irrational ), x ( where x is not a perfect xth power or a perfect square and is also, of course, rational).

Let a = $ (\sqrt[x]{x})^{\sqrt{x}} $

and b = $ \sqrt{x} $

Then in that case

a<sup>b</sup> = $ ((\sqrt[x]{x})^{\sqrt{x}})^{\sqrt{x}} $

=> a<sup>b</sup> =  $ (\sqrt[x]{x})^{x} $

=> a<sup>b</sup> = x

Yay! That means success! as x was a rational variable and now, at the end of the computation, we reached back to a rational solution.

**I have made posted this proof to Maths StackExchange, even after being fully aware of its rules, in order to ask if I have any errors in my solutions, or that the Gelfond-Schneider Theorem is wrong.**

Comment: The "theorem" you stated is just NOT the [Gelfand-Schneider Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem).

Comment: Why would you post a question with incorrect statements?

Answer (score 6):

The Gelfond-Schneider Theorem says that if $a$ and $b$ are **algebraic** numbers with $a\ne 0,1$, and $b$ irrational, then $a^b$ is transcendental.

In particular, it follows from the theorem that $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$ is transcendental.

Of course $(\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}})^{\sqrt{2}}$ is not transcendental. But that does not contradict Gelfrond-Schneider, since $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$ is not an algebraic number.

Answer (score 3):

Your work seems correct but the statement is also correct. It doesn't state that there are *only* $2$ numbers but *at least* two numbers. The distinction can be confusing but it is important.

Answer (score 1):

Also, I don't think you quite understand the proof you presented, you are missing an important step. It is not at all clear that $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$ is irrational (The actual Gelfond-Schneider theorem tells us it is, but that's way harder).  So without the Gelfond-Schneider theorem we have two cases, if it's rational then we could take $a = b = \sqrt{2}$ as our two irrational numbers, if it's irrational then we are in your case.